# Mithril component state renders differently with unshift

Tags: javascript, arrays, mithril.js

So, i have an array, i have 2 components(child and parent), i iterate through array within parent component, i render child components, i give them attrs(props) from array.

Child components have their attrs(props) increment and decrement.

Parent component can add new item into array and re-render.

QUESTION: Why chid it renders ok with .push() and bad with .unshift(). Also everything is ok with concat and [newItem, ...oldArray], but bad with same things when they add items in front of the array? Also how to properly .unshift() new items(comments, counters, images, posts, eg anything) into state, so they render first?

PS: This also occurs with React, Infero and Aurelia.

PPS: I'm more react guy, maybe i treat Mithril's vnode not how i suppose to.

```
const root = document.getElementById('root')

var data = [0, 12, -10, 1, 0]

class app {
    oninit(vnode){
        vnode.state.data = data
    }
    oncreate(vnode) {
        vnode.state.addCounter = function(e){
            vnode.state.data.unshift(1)
        }
    }
    view(vnode){
        if(vnode.state.data){
            return([
                m('button',{onclick: vnode.state.addCounter},'add another counter'),
                vnode.state.data.map((e,i)=>{
                    return(
                        m(Counter, {data: e, key: i})
                    )
                })
            ])
        }
    }
}

class Counter {
    oninit(vnode){
        vnode.state.data = vnode.attrs.data
        vnode.state.increment = function(e){
            vnode.state.data = vnode.state.data + 1
        }
        vnode.state.decrement = function(e){
            vnode.state.data = vnode.state.data - 1;
        }
    }
    view(vnode){
        return(
            m('p',{style: 'display:inline;margin: 10px;'},[
                m('b',{onclick: vnode.state.increment, style:'cursor: pointer'}, '+'),
                m('i', vnode.state.data),
                m('b',{onclick: vnode.state.decrement, style:'cursor: pointer'}, '-')
            ])
        )
    }
}

m.mount(root, app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the `key`. You use the array index as key when rendering the children:

```
vnode.state.data.map((e,i)=>{
    return(
        m(Counter, {data: e, key: i})
    )
})
```

The simple solution is to use a proper key, in this case the only thing that makes sense is the number passed to the child:

```
vnode.state.data.map((number)=>{
    return(
        m(Counter, {data: number, key: number})
    )
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kh0ggrb/

#### Where your code failed

Generally using array index as key is a bad idea (in any keyed library/framework including Mithril.js), and your use-case is a good example of why that is.

Let's go through what happens step-by-step:

**1: Setup**

You start with an array `[0, 12, -10, 1, 0]`, and render out `Counter``s for the respective numbers in the array. The new components have keys 0 through 4.

```
------------------------
| key | number | shows |
------------------------
|   0 |      0 |     0 |
|   1 |     12 |    12 |
|   2 |    -10 |   -10 |
|   3 |      1 |     1 |
|   4 |      0 |     0 |
------------------------
```

**2: Add to start of array**

You add `1` to the beginning of the array, getting `[1, 0, 12, -10, 1, 0]`. This works as you would expect. However, when you render it out, the first 5 children have a key that Mithril reconizes, and instead of creating new components, Mithril uses the same component as before. Thus, in your case the first five components are reused.

Because each of your `Counter``s only cares about the `attrs` it received **when it was craeted**:

```
class Counter {
    oninit(vnode){
        vnode.state.data = vnode.attrs.data
        ...
```

... reusing the same component to render a new number **will not work**.

```
------------------------------------------------
| key | current number |   prev number | shows |
------------------------------------------------
|   0 |              1 |             0 |     0 |
|   1 |              0 |            12 |    12 |
|   2 |             12 |           -10 |   -10 |
|   3 |            -10 |             1 |     1 |
|   4 |              1 |             0 |     0 |
|   5 |              0 | new component |     0 |
------------------------------------------------
```

The existing compoents reuse the number they were initialized with, and only the last one uses the number it receives in `attrs`.